# Grouping db entries when values to test for filtering are in separate entries

Tags: sql

having (simplified ) table entries as such:

```
uid               role_target_id
1                 'student'
1                 'employee'
2                 'other roles'
1                 'other roles'
other numbers     'other roles'
```

how can i return one single line corresponding to the uid user1 which is at the same time 'student' and 'employee ?

i am having this sql which is an OR operator for roles . I would like the same but with an AND operator for roles

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.uid AS uid
FROM
{users_field_data} u
LEFT OUTER JOIN {user__roles} ur ON ur.entity_id = u.uid
WHERE (u.uid > '1') AND (u.login < '1586448031') AND (u.login != '0') AND ((ur.roles_target_id IS NULL) OR (ur.roles_target_id IN ('authenticated', 'administrator', 'personnel_amu', 'etudiant_amu', 'affiliate_amu', 'membre_dosi', 'membre_du_site', 'gestionnaire', 'gestionnaire_axes_de_recherche', 'gestionnaire_services', 'admin_site', 'gestionnaire_projet')))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT u.uid
FROM users_field_data u JOIN user__roles
     role_target_id ur ON
     ur.entity_id = u.uid
WHERE (u.uid > '1') AND (u.login < '1586448031') AND 
      (u.login != '0') AND
      (ur.roles_target_id IN ('student', 'employee')
GROUP BY u.uid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;  -- both match
```

Comment: brilliant, that works but is there another method than the count=2 ? This sql is generated dynamically in php and the IN('student', 'employee') can well be IN ('role1', 'role2','role4') or something else

Comment: @Matoeil . . . It should be the number of elements in the list.  The code that generates the list should also know the size.